# Does LIMIT 1 have any performance boost?

Tags: mysql, performance, limit, crud

Does appended `LIMIT 1` after query have any performance boost?

...if there could be only one possible entry that matched (`WHERE` clause for primary key)?

```
SELECT `x`
FROM `unicorns`
WHERE `id` = 123
LIMIT 1
```

...the same, but now it's `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM `unicorns`
WHERE `id` = 123
LIMIT 1
```

...and `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `unicorns`
SET `rainbows` = `rainbows` + 1
WHERE `id` = 123
LIMIT 1
```

P.S. Column `id` is primary key so it's unique.

Thanks in an advice!

Comment: limit, in this case, should have no effect.  Also, you should not need quotes around your column names.

Comment: I personally feel it's still good for clarity and habbit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it depends do you have index on column or not

```
DELETE FROM `unicorns` WHERE `id` = 123 LIMIT 1
```

is pointless if id is Primary Key, but

```
DELETE FROM `unicorns` WHERE `noindexoclumn` = 123 LIMIT 1
```

will give u perfomance boost

Answer (score 0):

It'll boost performance in that the DB will only initiate a fetch of the rows that satisfied the conditions of the query. But on updates, what's the point? Especially if you're doing an exact match on a primary key - you'd only ever match one row to begin with, so there's no point in saying what amounts to "update this one row in the table, but only update one row at most".